# How to resolve "No suitable download server found" when updating?

Tags: updates, mirrors

I am a new user to Ubuntu 12.04. I have already connected to the Internet (without any firewall or proxy) and can browse the web. But whenever I am trying to update Ubuntu or trying to select the mirror for my location (Singapore) it just gives this error:

> NO SUITABLE DOWNLOAD SERVER FOUND. PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update by terminal ,open Terminal by ctrl+alt+T
Type

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

It will ask password, give password.
Packages will be automatically updated.

To Update by Synaptic

open synamptic , Click on reload.... It will show you list of packages that are available in new version. So are newbie to ubuntu, install synaptic by

Open Terminal,
type
`sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to update your Ubuntu. Here is the details.

## Easiest Way

As you are new to Ubuntu. May be you are not so comfortable with command line. In that case, this way will be best for you. The easiest way is using Update Manager. Normally if update manager gets any update, it'll notify you automatically. Otherwise, you can click on the GEAR icon on the top right of your screen, it will show you a menu. If your system has update then number 4 option will show **"Update Available"**, otherwise it'll show **"Software up to date"**. Click on this option, it'll open the Update Manager of Ubuntu. It'll show you the details of the updates available or not. Install the updates from here as your wish.

## Advanced Way

Press ctrl+alt+T. It'll open the terminal. Then type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It'll ask for your password. Give the password and press enter. Packages will be updated automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, I am a newbie at Linux and yet not familiar with the command line. But will like to learn it fast and slowly reduce my windows dependency to a minimal. Can you suggest any turorial/pdf to actually LEARN the terminal. I came across some in the web, but most of them contain a list of commands for copy paste or to mug. I like to get the feel of the command I am entering. Any suggestion please?

Comment: @SwagatoBarmanRoy: Try `The Command Line Crash Course` from http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/. Or see this post on AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/565/tips-for-getting-to-grips-with-the-command-line

Comment: @SwagatoBarmanRoy mmb puts here a great comment. Just following will be helpful enough, I think.